# How to get package directory workspace path eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I am trying to write or update .java file inside package programmingly but I am not getting correct path. Most of code return me path where i kept eclipse software but I need workspace path.I am working on localhost. Following codes, I am using

```
URL location = InstallationStepsServlet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    String directoryToCreateFile    =   location.getFile().replace(FilesName.SERVLET_INSTALLATION_STEPS+".class", "");

    out.println(directoryToCreateFile);
    out.println("<br/>"+System.getProperty("user.dir")+"<br/>");
    out.println(new File("CMS").getAbsolutePath());

    File file = new File(".");
    String currentDirectory = file.getAbsolutePath();
    out.println("<br/>Current working directory : "+currentDirectory);
```

None of the above code is working for me.

**Requirement**

My motive is to write in SiteConfig.java programmingly that is why I am trying to get directory path.

Will same code work for online servers also?

Comment: What do you want to achieve. Are you trying to recompile the SiteConfig later on? Usually when you deploy the application it will be in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: I will write user's database details in SiteConfig file that i will use in complete project.

Comment: If you write anything in the SiteConfig then it has to be recompile. If you writing some details like UserName or something of that sort think of storing it in DB or a file and access the file or DB